# bootstrap contact us form not working in smaller screen modes (using pull right)

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, formatting

I have a basic Bootstrap3 layout that looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <h2>Section 1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <h2>Section 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
         <h2>Section 3</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <h2>Section 4</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <h2>Section 5</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Section 3 has a basic Contact Us form, which works fine in full screen mode... But once reduced to a smaller size the user can not enter data.

When "pull-right" is removed the form funtions correctly in all size modes but then my vertical alignments with Section 4 and Section 5 are pushed down and out of line...

I need the form to work in all screen size modes and for the verticle alignment to be consistent - any help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: This layout doesn't really seem to make sense; Bootstrap is based on grids of size 12; you have the 3rd third (9-12) with pull-right, but it would already be the rightmost column, and the 4th and 5th would be a second row.

Comment: on smaller screen sizes, pull-right wouldn't make sense either, since you aren't using any `s` or `xs` column definitions.

Comment: I am using pull right in column3 and not creating an additional row for 4 & 5 so that 4 & 5 will align vertically with section 1 and 2 ... I was able to align 1 and 2 with 4 and 5 by 'nesting' 4 with 1 and 5 with 2 - but then 3 would get out of order in mobile view and get pushed to the end of the list... I asked this format question on a previous post and the above format was recommended...

Comment: `pull-right` wouldn't change the layout on medium screen sizes; on small or extra small screen sizes, it would make the column unusable because you don't have any definitions at all for those screen sizes.

Comment: if you want the columns to be 3 wide on *every* screen size, you should use `col-xs-4` instead of `col-md-4`.

Comment: by using 1 row I was hoping to better align content in section 4 & 5 with the 1 & 2 above... allowing section 3 to extent vertically downward - much like this stackoverflow page we're using... but with 3 columns instead of 2

Comment: are you using any sort of client side framework? is there any way you could dynamically add the `pull-right` using JavaScript after detecting a screen size maybe?

Answer (score 1):

From your question it is really difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve (I mean the layout) but as I see you use .pull-right class with .col-md-X and as far as I know it is a wrong approach because all .col-md-X classes have 'float: left; width: x%;' styles. Applying 'float: right' brakes your grid.

Instead you should have a look at these classes .col-md-push-X and .col-md-pull-X More info you can find in the official docs http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

UPD try this http://plnkr.co/edit/ujbqGvGwCnht9CGmKQ1r?p=preview resize plunker result window to see the result

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <h2>Section 1</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
      <h2>Section 3</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
      <h2>Section 2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <h2>Section 4</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <h2>Section 5</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response - is it possible to vertically align content that is uneven with the Bootstrap grid system alone - or does it still require CSS changes... The above successfully allows me to vertically align section 1 & 2 with section 4 & 5 while allowing Section 3 (a contact form) to extend down and beside section 5... You're right formatting is the real problem I have here...

Comment: yuyokk - with your code, now enter text into Section 3 --- Section 4 and 5 get pushed down... I don't want this to happen...

Comment: Thank you - but then in mobile view section 3 get pushed to the end of the list of columns... I'm trying to also keep section 3 in order regardless of the viewport..